# TypeScript still fires error ts2571 after type checking of an unknown variable

Tags: typescript

For example, the following will cause an `Object is of type 'unknown'.` error:

```js
let obj: {[key: string]: unknown} = {hello: ["world", "!"]}; // Maybe anything of the same shape

let key = "hello"; // Maybe any key of obj

if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) obj[key][1] = obj[key][0];
```

while the following does not:

```js
let obj: {[key: string]: unknown} = {hello: ["world", "!"]}; // Maybe anything of the same shape

let key = "hello"; // Maybe any key of obj

let array = obj[key];

if (Array.isArray(array)) array[1] = array[0];
```

Is this an excepted behaviour (or possibly a bug)?

---

OK, a reason I can think of is a getter which return different values each time:

```js
const values = ["hello", 16, true];

let obj: {x: number, [key: string]: unknown} = {
    x: 0,
    get y() {
        return values[this.x = (this.x + 1) % values.length];
    }
};
```

Is this a concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior in current TypeScript versions, it should get better in TypeScript 4.4 - see examples in section "[Control Flow Analysis of Aliased Conditions and Discriminants](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-rc/#cfa-aliased-conditions)" in TS 4.4 RC blogpost.

Comment: Great – I am so lucky that I encounter this problem just before TypeScript is going to fix it! I will try it next week when the stable version is released.